# SQL query to obtain entire tree by root id

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, hierarchical-data, hierarchical-query

I have a table to store binary tree data in the following structure

[image]

Lets say for userId 27, currently I'm fetching a bunch of rows and building the tree in code.

Is there an efficient way to fetch the all the rows which belonging to the tree for userId 27 (as nodes) via sql query? 
 I have MySQL 8.0.21.

Comment: What do you mean: "*as nodes*"? SQL is used to fetch, modify data, but not for data graphical presentation. What have you tried so far? What's expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, one option uses a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select t.* from mytable where userid = 27
    union all
    select t.*
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.parentid = c.userid
)
select * from cte
```